# Setting a SCNTechnique stops SCNSceneRendererDelegate

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, scenekit, deferred-rendering

When I set a SCNTechnique to my SCNView, my SCNSceneRendererDelegate stops to work. Are there any workarounds? I want to execute some code before and after scene rendering. I've tried to reset the delegate, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Answer (score 1):

You must use the scenekit COLOR output in a technique pass for the delegates to work

Answer (score 0):

To make this work I added:

```
"inputs" : {"color" : "COLOR" }
```

to the technique definition.